# Knockout missing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I follow this tutorial: http://knockoutmvc.com/GiftList to create ediable list.
but when i run code. It noticed a error that

> The type or namespace name 'PerpetuumSoft' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the error from this line:

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.GiftListModel
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout //Error in this line 


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext(); //and also Error in this line 
}
```

I include knockout in bundle

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
        "~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js",
        "~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.debug.js"));
```

And add this code in share layout name _Layout.cstml

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
```

Actually, I search this tutorial because I want to create a view where user can edit the list, the data can only be saved when user click button save, that mean user can do whatever they want. Database is updated only when button save is fired. If you know any other ways to do it without using any extension or plug-in, please recommend it (because I have to use ASP .NET MVC 4 Only, no adding any more extension).Thank you so much.

This is code in view

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.GiftListModel
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@{
  var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<p>You have asked for @ko.Html.Span(m => m.Gifts.Count) gift(s)</p>
<form id="myform">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      @using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => m.Gifts))
      {
        <tr>
          <td>Gift name:@items.Html.TextBox(item => item.Title, new { @class = "required" }).UniqueName()</td>
          <td>Price: $@items.Html.TextBox(item => item.Price, new { @class = "required number" }).UniqueName()</td>
          <td>@ko.Html.Button("Delete", "RemoveGift", "GiftList", new { index = items.GetIndex() })</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>

  @ko.Html.Button("Add", "AddGift", "GiftList")
  <button @ko.Bind.Enable(m => m.Gifts.Count > 0) type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
@using (ko.If(m => m.ServerTime.Length > 0))
{
  <p>Saved at @ko.Html.Span(m => m.ServerTime)</p>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#myform").ajaxForm();
  $("#myform").validate({ submitHandler: function () { @ko.ServerAction("Save", "GiftList"); } });
</script>
<style scoped="scoped">
  input.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #FDC;
  }

  label.error {
    display: block;
    color: Red;
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
</style>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing the [following Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PerpetuumSoft.Knockout/) by Perpetuumsoft. This package provides the MVC knockout helpers which are used in that tutorial.

If you don't want to use that package, remove the using statement and that `var ko` line. Just make sure you `applyBindings` somewhere on your view model.

Comment: that mean i have to install: PerpetuumSoft.Knockout 0.5.7.2. Do you know any other way to solve my problem

Comment: @TranDuyLinh Yep, whichever the latest package is (nuget will take care of that for you though). You could solve the problem by removing those Html helper references and writing the knockout code yourself.

Comment: its the first time i use Knockout, can you please explain more about this

Comment: @TranDuyLinh I'd read about observables, you need to tell knockout what your view model is, then it can bind to it to do it's work. More info here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: that mean instead of using var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext(); i have to use var ko = {
    title: 'ABC',
    price: 123
}; for example

Comment: @TranDuyLinh Not exactly no, if I was you I would do the tutorials on the Knockout site they're much better and easier to understand (that's what I did to first learn it)

Comment: yes, i think i miss basic understand about knockout. but the time for my project is limit, so i decide to read this website: http://knockoutmvc.com/ Its relative to my project (I do MVC 4).

Comment: @TranDuyLinh That's fine if you use that website, but that's based on the third party Knockout MVC helpers so you'll have to use that. The knockout examples apply everywhere not just MVC and those MVC helpers will simply write the corresponding knockout. The tutorials on the knockout site are really simple and quick :)